# Include NULL values when copying csv using psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, psql

I have a csv with various data formats that I am trying to copy in to postgres.  I am encountering this error every time because at line 97789 I have a few columns with empty cells.

Rather than deleting this row (and other rows that may contain NULL values), I'd like to find a solution to including them in the database. Column `ma effective date` is supposed to take an integer value.  But when I try to use the following code - it doesn't work, probably because I am trying to input NULL as a string:

```
oakland=# \copy test_import FROM '/Users/Downloads/IE670_test.csv' DELIMITER ','  NULL AS 'NULL' csv
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "        "
CONTEXT:  COPY test_import, line 97789, column ma effective date (ccyymmdd): "        "
```

however, switching to `NULL as NULL` also doesn't work and produces a syntax error in `psql`.  Is there an effective solution to including NULL values regardless of the data type in the column?

Here is the offending line in raw format:

```
048A706200600,48A-7062-6     ,17,3,5815,PRESLEY WAY                                       ,          ,OAKLAND                       ,94618,    ," $102,150.00 "," $38,259.00 ", $-   , $-   , $-   , $-   , $-   ," $7,000.00 ", $-   ," $133,409.00 ",2015,139807,20150527,20150901, ,                    ,                                                  ,                                                            ,          ,                              ,     ,    ,  , ,        , ,1100,Single family residential homes used as such
```

Comment: the entire row? the content of the offending cell is "               " I guess.

Comment: Not sure how I can do that with the comma separators included. I have about 40 columns and am using Open Office

Comment: a csv file can be opened in any text editor

Comment: done, I edited the question

Comment: well you don't have null in your CSV! what you have is a bunch of spaces and `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "        "` suddenly begins to make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the null-valued cells are truly empty, omit the `NULL AS 'NULL'` clause. Otherwise (as appears to be the case), replace the `'NULL'` *string* with a string containing whatever is in those cells. You may need to ensure that the null values in the csv are consistent.

test.csv (one-space null):

```
1, ,3
```

SQL

```
create table csv (one int, two int, three int);
```

One space as null:

```
\copy csv from '~/test.csv' delimiter ',' null as ' ' csv;
COPY 1
```

Two spaces as null:

```
\copy csv from '~/test.csv' delimiter ',' null as '  ' csv;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: " "
CONTEXT:  COPY csv, line 1, column two: " "
```

Comment: I added an example -- it looks like your null cell contains _eight_ spaces (possibly a tab that got mangled by pasting?), not one, going by your error message above.

Comment: the confusing part is that I have so many empty cells throughout the table, just not in that particular column until line 97789.  What could be causing the error in this particular column?  There are many others that are of integer data type.

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that line 97789 is the first in which there is an empty cell being recorded as an integer field, although naturally this can't be confirmed without inspecting lines 1-97788. If you have empty cells but they're going into text columns, that's fine; it's only when it has to convert and can't that you'll see errors.

Comment: We need devination to be able to tell you what caused that error in that particular line. You apparently have different number of spaces as null in different columns. Else an adaptation of this answer would work for you. Your best bet is to pre process your CSV to convert all these blanks of variable lengths to the same null representation